# How do I group by a column, and count values in separate columns (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's an example data:

```
data = [['a1', 1, 'a'], ['b1', 2, 'b'], ['a1', 3, 'a'], ['c1', 4, 'c'], ['b1', 5, 'a'], ['a1', 6, 'b'], ['c1', 7, 'a'], ['a1', 8, 'a']] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['user', 'house', 'type']) 

user house type
a1     1    a
b1     2    b
a1     3    a
c1     4    c
b1     5    a
a1     6    b
c1     7    a
a1     8    a
```

The final output that I want is this (the types need to be their own columns):

```
user houses a b c    
a1      4   3 1 0
b1      2   1 1 0
c1      2   1 0 1
```

Currently, I'm able to get it by using the following code:

```
house = df.groupby(['user']).agg(houses=('house', 'count'))
a = df[df['type']=='a'].groupby(['user']).agg(a=('type', 'count'))
b = df[df['type']=='b'].groupby(['user']).agg(b=('type', 'count'))
c = df[df['type']=='c'].groupby(['user']).agg(c=('type', 'count'))

final = house.merge(a,on='user', how='left').merge(b,on='user', how='left').merge(c,on='user', how='left')
```

Is there a simpler, cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Side note: well done on posting a well structured question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `GroupBy.size` with `pd.crosstab` and `join`:

```
grps = pd.crosstab(df['user'], df['type']).join(df.groupby('user')['house'].size())

      a  b  c  house
user                
a1    3  1  0      4
b1    1  1  0      2
c1    1  0  1      2
```

---

If you want `user` back as column, use `reset_index`:

```
print(grps.reset_index())

  user  a  b  c  house
0   a1  3  1  0      4
1   b1  1  1  0      2
2   c1  1  0  1      2
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way using [`get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `groupby()` and `sum`.

```
df['house']=1
df.drop('type',axis=1).assign(**pd.get_dummies(df['type'])).groupby('user').sum()
```

---

```
      house  a  b  c
user                
a1        4  3  1  0
b1        2  1  1  0
c1        2  1  0  1
```

Answer (score 5):

I will do `crosstab` with `margins=True`

```
pd.crosstab(df.user,df.type,margins=True,margins_name='House').drop('House')
Out[51]: 
type  a  b  c  House
user                
a1    3  1  0      4
b1    1  1  0      2
c1    1  0  1      2
```

Comment: This code works for this case, but assumes that each house has been assigned a type (which is a fair assumption for the most part). However, if a house is of type NaN, then the total for the "House" column would be incorrect. But this code is still useful when you do need to sum categories in this way.